# Desserializar Json e colocar os valores em views

Tags: android, json, desserialização

Bom, o que quero fazer é uma activity onde um Json seja consumido. O problema é que todos tutoriais mostram somente como retornar um Json num listview. O que quero é uma estrutura mais ou menos assim:

1. Título : `Textview`;
2. Imagem : `Imageview`;
3. Texto  : `Textview`;

Isso vindo de um único Json, como no exemplo:

```
{ 
 "item":[
      { "titulo":"Recomendação",
        "imagem":"http://i.imgur.com/Bl0jBTc.png",
        "texto":"Texto",
      }
     ]
 }
```

Atualmente uso Picasso pra carregar imagens.
Como seria um bom jeito de se fazer?

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski uso ela atualmente. O que preciso é saber como exibiria esse json em uma tela simples, porque todos os tutoriais que vi só mostram como exibir o json num listview

Comment: Só para agregar conhecimento, veja também o [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) que por ventura é muito bom também.

Comment: @AckLay me falaram do Glide e Picasso, aí escolhi o Picasso. Mas depois que já tinha feito tudo fui ver e parece que o glide é melhor, aceita gifs, etc. Acho que vou substituir o picasso quando tiver com tempo.

Comment: @Marceloawq acho que tendi o que você quer porem sem tempo agora. Você tem está usando o com.google.gson.Gson? Mais tarde se ninguém tiver respondido, coloco uma resposta aqui.

Comment: @AckLay não, no tutorial que segui ele mostra com `org.json`

Comment: O Gson ajuda bastante viu! Depois dê uma olhada também.

Comment: @AckLay vou olhar sim. Tô começando a estudar sobre Json e tudo é bem vindo, obrigado pela dica!

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski corrigido

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro terá de desserializar o Json para obter cada uma das partes.

```
String json = "{ \"item\":[{ \"titulo\":\"Recomendação\",\"imagem\":\"http://i.imgur.com/Bl0jBTc.png\", \"texto\":\"Texto\"} ]}";
String titulo;
String imagem;
String texto;
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("item");

    JSONObject jsonArrayJSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
    titulo = jsonArrayJSONObject.getString("titulo");
    imagem = jsonArrayJSONObject.getString("imagem");
    texto = jsonArrayJSONObject.getString("texto");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Use a string `image` para fazer o download da imagem.
As outras coloque-as no respectivo TextView.

Comment: perfeito. Exatamente o que eu precisava

Answer (score 2):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



     private final String JSON_CONTENT = "{ \"item\": [{ \"titulo\": \"Recomendação\", \"imagem\": \"http://i.imgur.com/Bl0jBTc.png\", \"texto\": \"Texto\" }] }";

    TextView titulo;
    TextView texto;
    ImageView imagem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Carregando os elementos da tela
        titulo = TextView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.titulo));
        texto = TextView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.texto));
        imagem = ImageView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.imagem));


        try{
            // transformamos a String em JsonObjetc (provavelmente, aqui voce deve pegar da web)
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(JSON_CONTENT);
            // Pegamos a lista item!
            final JSONArray lista = json.getJSONArray("item");
            // neste caso, vamos pegar o primeiro item da lista!
            final JSONObject jsonObject = lista.getJSONObject(0);
            // Setamos o titulo
            titulo.setText(jsonObject.getString("titulo"));
            // Setamos o texto
            texto.setText(jsonObject.getString("texto"));
            //adicionamos a imagem através do picasso
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load( jsonObject.getString("imagem")).into(imagem);
        }catch (final Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: o @ramaral deu uma sugestão parecida. Fiz aqui e deu certo, basicamente do jeito que você fez.

Answer (score 0):

Recebe um JSON parecido com esse:

```
 { 
     "itens":[
          { "titulo":"Titulo 0001",
            "texto":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ",
            "imagem":"http://seurepositorio/p/imagem1.png" },

          { "titulo":"Titulo 0002",
             "texto":"adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor ",
             "imagem":"http://seurepositorio/p/imagem2.png" }

           ....
           e segue...

         ]
   }
```

E faz outra requisição para buscar as imagens um código tipo esse:

```
URL url = new URL(imagem);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: Julgo que a dificuldade do AP é desserializar o json e colocar no layout.

Comment: desse jeito teria que colocar num listview, que é o que não quero. O que preciso é que tenha somente um "itens" e ao invés de colocar num listview, colocar no layout como foi dito na pergunta

Comment: Hmm. Você faz a requisição dos JSON, com um filtro especifico, tal que volte apenas um item, coloca o resultado do titulo e texto em TEXTVIEWS e faz a requisição da imagem para carrega-la numa IMAGEVIEW.

Answer (score -1):

o json viria titulo, url imagem, e texto.
Se for numa lista, você precisa criar um listview com um adpter para funcionar conforme você precisa, agora se for uma tela simples, basta você deserializar o json e colocar no seu layout.

```
{"titulo":"seu titulo", "imagem":"http://urlimagem.com/imagem.jpg", "texto":"seu texto"}
```

Comment: Julgo que a dificuldade do AP é desserializar o json e colocar no layout.

Comment: Para desseiralizar pode fazer na unha, pegando o json, transformando em objeto e colocar no layout).
Ou usar bibliotecas como retrofit, voley, etc.
Ai teria que dar uma pesquisada como cada uma funciona.

Comment: O que eu quis dizer é se a resposta não disser como desserializar o json e colocar no layout ela não ajudará o AP(não responde à pergunta)